# Trying to debug program through mocha (using --debug-brk) debugs mocha itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mocha.js

I installed this open source projects and mocha tests run but I want to debug the functions called by the tests but when I try to debug (using mocha --debug-brk), i see that debug is in the mocha code itself..

How do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get past this same issue by using [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) to add my real breakpoint, and just click pause/continue, which will stop at the real breakpoint then.