# mocha --inspect-brk lets me inspect mocha's code - not my own

Tags: node.js, debugging, mocha.js

Following [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028932/run-node-inspector-with-mocha) I attempted to debug a mocha test script via the following:

```
mocha --inspect-brk ./tests/foo.test.js
```

This does indeed present an inspector URL that I can bind to in Chrome, but the "sources" are populated only with the source of mocha itself, not my code - is there something I need to change to get the inspector to bring up my code and not mocha's?

(I did see a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368506/trying-to-debug-program-through-mocha-using-debug-brk-debugs-mocha-itself) but I'm hoping for an answer that doesn't involve bringing in another dependency like node-inspector.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `debugger` to one of your tests. When you resume in dev tools, execution will pause in your test code and you can browse your files.

```
it('should replace a template string', function(){
  debugger
  expect( Helper.templateString('{{a}}', {a:2}) ).to.equal( '2' )
})
```

You can also step over `_mocha` until it loads the files, which is around line 460 in v5.0.4, labeled `requires`:

```
// requires

requires.forEach(mod => {
  require(mod);
});
```

After this you can browse your files and set break points. Dev tools will remember the break points for the next run.